# VStack inside ForEach inside Array[Views]

Tags: ios, arrays, swiftui, stepper

Getting Array size = 1 but i am adding 4 objects in it which is showing.

In SwiftUI i am putting VStack inside ForEach loop in an Array containing views. which using above data creating only 1 step with 4 objects in it.

I am basically parsing the model object of data from API and using that model to create dynamic views.

FYI - I am using SwiftUI first time and passing that model from my UIKit ViewController to SwiftUI View file.

Param is passing and working fine.

Furthermore i am creating [StepperView](https://github.com/badrinathvm/StepperView) for tracking like in parcel delivery.

Pasting my UIClass code here for better idea.
(I have pasted just main core code needed for understanding so dont worry about other implementations of StepperView)

```
struct TrackingStepperView: View {
    var trackingData : [TrackingModel]?
    init(param: [TrackingModel]?) {
        self.trackingData = param
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        let steps = [
            ForEach(trackingData!) { item in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(item.getTitle()!).eraseToAnyView()
                    Text(item.getDescription()!).eraseToAnyView()
                    Text(item.getDateTime()!).eraseToAnyView()
                }
                .background(Color(UIColor.clear))
            }
        ]
        
        let _ = print("steps.count = ", steps.count)
        
        StepperView()
            .addSteps(steps)
    }
}
```

Also if i try to work with arrays like in swift UIKit. Getting following errors

- StepperView() Type ‘any View’ cannot conform to ‘View’
- Types can conform to protocols
- Type ‘()’ cannot conform to ‘View’
- Type ‘()’ cannot conform to ‘AccessibilityRotorContent’
- Type ‘any View’ cannot
  conform to ‘View’

Thanks for taking time to reading it out.

Comment: This isn’t how SwiftUI works. You shouldn’t be trying to store Views in an array and passing them to something to some other view. Probably a good idea to review some SwiftUI tutorials to get the basics of how the declarative design works.

Comment: In SwiftUI you change states to present different UI views, it is not like UIKit ViewController.
Note, the `ForEach` is not the "normal" looping foreach, it is a SwiftUI element (a View) that returns other Views.
**Review SwiftUI concepts** by following some tutorials, you will see none store Views in an Array. Your code is definitely not the way SwiftUI is meant to be used.
It is crucial to understand SwiftUI **declarative syntax**.

Answer (score 0):

I will correct your code to a working version with comments, see if it's useful:

1. In Swift, you usually don't need init like you provided: your `trackingData` is already internal, so you should be able to run a synthesized  init without creating your custom one.
2. Your `TrackingData` should conform to protocol `Identifiable`. (Optionally) I would also change `TrackingModel` so that instead of getters like `getTitle()`, you access properties:

   ```
   struct TrackingModel: Identifiable {
       let title: String?
       let description: String?
       let dateTime: Date?

       // Identifiable: as example, sing title, but use whatever is unique
       var id: String {
           title ?? UUID().uuidString
       }
   }
   ```
3. Express your input data as a `@State` or `@Environment` (depending on your needs). For example:

   ```
   @State var trackingData: [TrackingModel]
   ```
4. In the `body`, first of all you need some sort of container on top level. Based on your data, I'd suggest starting from `List`. It has some issues, but overall it's the most traditional way to display an array of data:

   ```
    var body: some View {
        List {
            // Your items here
        }
    }
   ```
5. Also avoid force unwrap. Instead, provide a default value.
6. Iterate over *data* and display (don't store) the views:

So here's the final version of your view:

```
struct TrackingModel: Identifiable {
    
    var id: String {
        title ?? UUID().uuidString
    }
    
    let title: String?
    let description: String?
    let dateTime: Date?
}

struct TrackingStepperView: View {
    
    @State var trackingData: [TrackingModel]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(trackingData) { item in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(item.title ?? "Unknown")
                    Text(item.description ?? "")
                    Text(item.dateTime?.ISO8601Format() ?? "--")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It can be instantiated by providing a tracking data:

```
TrackingStepperView(trackingData: [
            TrackingModel(title: "one", description: "one one", dateTime: .now),
            TrackingModel(title: "two", description: "two two", dateTime: .now)
        ])
```

Yes, you can make tracking data optional, but I would say ideally, you don't: if there's no tracking data, no point to display this view at all. Instead the parent view / caller can do something like:

```
if let trackingData = trackingData {
    TrackingStepperView(trackingData: trackingData)
} else {
    EmptyView() // or some other view for empty state
}
```